# ffmpeg inaccurate seeking keyframes with H265 vcopy

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, seek, hevc

I've got an H265 4K MP4 29.97fps video with a GOP-size of exactly 30 frames.
When I try to cut from the start using :

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_1SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_2SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 3 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_3SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 4 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_4SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_5SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 6 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_6SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 7 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_7SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 8 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_8SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 9 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy OUTPUT_9SEC.MP4
```

The output videos starts at either 0 (-ss 1~4), 4 (-ss 5~8) or 8 sec (-ss 9) as shown below:

[image: Premiere Pro Timeline]

So it seems ffmpeg somehow detect a GOP of 4 seconds instead of 1 seconds. Is it normal ?

Also, how can I burn the correct timecode in the output video ?
For example, I tried many combinations such as:

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy -timecode 00:00:05:00 OUTPUT_5SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy -copyts OUTPUT_5SEC.MP4
ffmpeg -start_at_zero -ss 5 -i INPUT.MP4 -vcodec copy -copyts OUTPUT_5SEC.MP4
```

But it either give me the exact timecode I put (first line) or starts at zero (two last lines)

Originally, I was thinking about seeking at the exact second (or a few frame after) so I knew I would get a keyframe so I could guess the exact timecode the output would start, but it seems ffmpeg -ss is not exactly based on keyframes ? Maybe I'm missing something here ? Thanks for the help.

**Additionnal infos**

I'd like to script the cut process, that's why I want to know where this 4-sec "keyframe interval" come from.

Here is the ffprobe output of my input:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'INPUT.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
    comment         : DE=None, Mode=M, DSW=0001
    location-{    : +XX.4914-0XX.5164+XX.000000/
    location        : +XX.4914-0XX.5164+XX.000000/
  Duration: 00:01:45.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 100065 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 4096x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 256:135], 100062 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

Here is the command I used to check gop-size ('I' type at 1,31,61,... and 'P' in between):

```
ffprobe -i INPUT.MP4 -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pict_type -of csv > OUTPUT.CSV
```

ffmpeg version **N-86330-gbd1179e** and ffmpeg version **N-86330-gbd1179e**

**Edit :** [Sample video here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-snEjSQIoBecDhSZGJCTk5qYkk)

Comment: What's the output of `ffprobe -i INPUT.MP4 -select_streams v -show_entries frame=key_frame -of csv > OUTPUT.CSV`

Comment: `frame,I` on line 1,31,61,... and `frame,P` on all other lines

Comment: key_frame value not pict_type. Not all I frames are IDR frames.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Same pattern but with `frame,1` on line 1,31,61... and `frame,0` on all other lines.

Comment: Ok, try the copy with only the video track mapped (`-map 0:v`). The timecode is a single encoded string, not a timekeeping metadatum.

Comment: Same result with `ffmpeg -ss 7 -i INPUT.MP4 -map 0:v -vcodec copy OUTPUT_7SEC.MP4`. Thanks for the timecode explanation.

Comment: Can you share the whole or part of the file?

Comment: Sure. I've just added a link at the bottom of my message. Thanks for looking into it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is a keyframe each second, in the MOOV box, only three frames are set as sync samples

```
/moov/trak/mdia/minf/stbl/stss                              @ 0x77e8515
  Box size: 0x1c    version: 0x0    flags: 0x0
  entry_count:              0x3
    sample_number:
    0x1    0x79    0xf1
```

(those are the 1st, 121st and 241st frames.)

FFmpeg relies on this info when seeking.

---

Workaround is to mux to TS and then remux to MP4.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy input.ts
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -c copy newinput.mp4
```

Or in one command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f mpegts - | ffmpeg -f mpegts -i - -c copy newinput.mp4
```

MPEG-TS files don't have an index so if you want to use that file for extraction, specify a seek point **before** the keyframe you wish to cut from.

As to why the sync table is that way, don't know. That's upto the original writing application and the settings/arguments used there.

Comment: Thanks for these useful infos. I can now split newinput.mp4 each seconds, but the resulting clips contains jumps, black and green frames + compression blocks. I ended up converting all my h265 to DnxHR, and I keep the full unedited h265 for archive. I really appreciate the time you took to investigate this, now I understand more about keyframes stuff.